# The OLD: and the NEW:

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

I am using parameters `&TableName`

My query comes back to me in the results with an **OLD:** tag before it, and again with a **New:** tag (the variable is replaced with the value that I have typed in) and then my results follow this.

How do I get rid of this annoying return and change it to just display my results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL*Plus I think you mean `SET VERIFY OFF`. I don't have SQL Developer to hand to check it's the same but I'd imagine so.

**Edited to add example** and confirm it does work in SQL Developer too.

```
define tmpVar='test'

set verify on

select '&tmpVar' from dual;

set verify off

select '&tmpVar' from dual;
```

which produces:

```
old:select '&tmpVar' from dual
new:select 'test' from dual
'TEST' 
------ 
test   

'TEST' 
------ 
test
```

The link @a_horse_with_no_name provided shows this too.